# Searching for name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When I type G in the field and it filters out all the names whose names contain g in any part of their name. I want only to filter which starts with G. To sort this, i added something like this.

```
patientSearchResult[i].LastName.toUpperCase().charAt(0)
```

But now when i type Gr. i don't get Greg's result... why?

Comment: You need to post a lot more code for context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a regular expression coupled with an array filter for this. Try this:

```
var patients = [
    "Greg",
    "Anna",
    "Slartibartfarst"
    ];

var input = "Gr";
var re = new RegExp(input+'.+$', 'i');
patients = patients.filter(function(e, i, a){
    return e.search(re) != -1;
});
console.log(patients);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2R44X/

Comment: `indexOf()` isn't a much simpler solution?

Comment: Sure, if you're searching *anywhere* in the string. For example, if the name "Sirgrumblebutt" is valid with the search term "Gr". Using the filter method, you can specify *exact* patterns to be matched. That is, unless `indexOf` supports regex, then yes you're absolutely correct.

Comment: Ah, shoulda read the question more thoroughly. Although if you use `indexOf`, you'll have to run through the entire list every time a new character is entered, where if you filter it, you reduce the number of steps required every time. Of course, this is only really relevant to large datasets.

Comment: Yeah, I was thrown off by the charAt approach - I did read the question (several times), I just mistook the approach.

Comment: Actually, what does "I want only to filter which starts with G." mean then?

Comment: This worked fine for partial search terms but didn't work for the complete search term.  
Such as 'Greg', to fix that I replaced '+' with '*' i.e. new RegExp(input+'.*$', 'i');

Answer (score 1):

charAt returns just the character at the specified index.

You could use `patientSearchResult[i].LastName.toUpperCase().substr(0,2)` where `2` should be replaqced with the length of the string you're searching for.

Comment: @John Coopper - `indexOf()` will get you what you want.

Comment: @Jared indexOf would find the search string anywhere in the source string.

Comment: And if it equaled 0, then the string started with the search value, correct?

Comment: One minute, I read the question and I think they're asking for one approach. Then, I reread it and I think another. Then I reread it... And I'm all confused.

Comment: Depending on what the OP is wanting, `.substring()` could also work in the right context.

Answer (score 1):

For a more generic solution, you could use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with regexp searches to make query functions:

```
var patientRecord = [
        {firstname: 'Bob',lastname: 'Grown'},
        {firstname: 'Alexa',lastname: 'Ace'},
        {firstname: 'Chris',lastname: 'Green'}
    ];

var makeQuery = function(property, regexp) {
        // return a callback function for filter, see MDC docs for Array.filter
        return function(elem, index, array) {
            return elem[property].search(regexp) !== -1;
        };
    };

var q = makeQuery('lastname', /^g/i); // ^ = from beginning, i = "ignore case"

patientRecord.filter(q);
```

Console output:

```
[
    {
        firstname: "Bob",
        lastname: "Grown",
        __proto__: Object
    }, 
    {
        firstname: "Chris",
        lastname: "Green",
        __proto__: Object
    }
]
```

Comment: This can be used to query different properties that are strings – or with slight modification, have `toString()`, and also accomodates search suggestions if given `patientRecord.filter(makeQuery('lastname', new RegExp(input+'.+$', 'i'))` like in Demian's answer.

Comment: `makeQuery` could be used without the `var q = ...`, like: `patientRecord.filter(makeQuery('lastname', /^g/i));`, but that enables reuse of the query later.